# Calling different methods from the same loop with delay

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How can I call different methods in the same loop with delay?

```
time 0: call A  
+100ms: call B  
+100ms: call C  
+100ms: call D  
...  
+100ms: call X  
stopLoop()
```

I tried:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            call A();
                            sleep(100);
                            call B();
                            sleep(100);
                            call C();
                            sleep(100);
                            call D();
                            sleep(100);
                            call E();
                            sleep(100);

                            thread.stop(); ???
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
```

It is working except the stop(), plus it doesn't look logical to kill a thread from inside the same thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread.interrupt() is a perfectly acceptable way of doing this.

[Thread#interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> Interrupts this thread. Unless the current thread is interrupting
>   itself, which is always permitted, the checkAccess method of this
>   thread is invoked, which may cause a SecurityException to be thrown.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.
>
> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.

[Why Are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend, 
Thread.resume and Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit Deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Try something like this:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    //Call methods .
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the OP how to use it properly? Right now this should be a comment.

Comment: Is it better to use `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` or cover the loop with `while()` ?